# Sending data at 1Hz from collectd to influxdb, but only seeing data at 0.1Hz in Grafana

Tags: collectd, grafana

I have `Interval 1` in collectd.conf, and have verified with tshark that many packets are being sent every second. And yet, when I graph my metrics in grafana, I only see data points once every 10 seconds. I am able to INCREASE the interval from 10 to 30s and I see that reflected in Grafana. But when I try to DECREASE the interval, I can't get the resolution any lower than 10s.

My first theory was that influxdb batching was causing problems. But this keeps happening even when I set `INFLUXDB_COLLECTD_BATCH_TIMEOUT=1s`.

Where else might this magic 10s configuration setting be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with my python collectd plugin. It was not respecting the `interval` field of `register_read()`. Other, standard plugins were working properly.